# Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dhcp, dhclient

Recently my `syslog` is getting flooded with these messages, every couple of seconds:

```
Aug 13 16:02:15 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:02:15 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:02:15 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
Aug 13 16:02:30 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:02:30 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:02:30 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
Aug 13 16:02:42 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:02:42 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:02:42 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
Aug 13 16:02:56 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:02:56 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:02:56 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
Aug 13 16:03:05 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:03:05 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:03:05 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
Aug 13 16:03:16 lati dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x204c0015)
Aug 13 16:03:16 lati dhclient: send_packet: No such device or address
Aug 13 16:03:16 lati dhclient: dhclient.c:2038: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan2 interface.
```

I am connected to my router via wifi, and the internet connection seems to be ok at the moment.

This is my network configuration:

```
[connection]
id=Olez
uuid=#####
type=802-11-wireless
timestamp=1466575089

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=Olez
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=#####
seen-bssids=#####;
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=#####

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

Should I worry about this? Can I do something to fix it? Can it be a problem with the router?

---

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-40-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14

---

My network info:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 04
       serial: ec:f4:bb:55:4f:c5
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.7-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:59 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan2
       version: 73
       serial: f8:16:54:0c:6d:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-40-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 ip=10.0.0.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:63 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

The result of `dmesg | grep -i firmware` is

```
[    0.126773] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.241202] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[    3.242375] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.435452] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[11374.953742] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you try first upgrading the firmware for your device. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and let us know if the performance has improved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That link does not exist. And: shouldn't aptitude update my device firmware on a normal update?

Comment: Firm ware is normally updated, however to get the very latest, I suggest the process in my answer. I have edited the link. It was current in August when I posted it but not today.

Comment: Well, it seems like the message still appears in the logs after installing the new firmware...)